# Does listen() backlog affect established TCP connections?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

Would it be naive to create a TCP socket with a listen backlog set to minimum as a way of rate limiting new incoming connections? The server workload in question doesn't expect many new connections at any time but spends a lot of time servicing long open persistent connections. It appears that new incoming connections shouldn't affect established connections, though I've been unable to find any definitive answer in any text. Is it possible for failed new incoming connections to create some kind of TCP traffic congestion on the server with the packets it's receiving or are they dropped fast enough that it has no effect on any buffers or other part of the network stack?

Specifically the platform in use is Linux, and although it may be handled differently in different OSs, I expect them to all behave roughly the same.

**EDIT** What I mean by the "same" is that backlog doesn't affect established connections, though I do understand Linux discards them while Windows sends a reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does listen() backlog affect established TCP connections?

It affects established connections that the server hasn't accepted yet via `accept(),` only in the sense that it limits the number of such connections that can exist.

> Would it be naive to create a TCP socket with a listen backlog set to minimum as a way of rate limiting new incoming connections?

All it would accomplish would be to unnecessarily fail some connecting clients. They won't get any service until your server gets around to it anyway, and once the backlog queue fills they are rate-limited by your service code anyway. There is no particular reason why shortening the queue would have any beneficial effect. The other problem with the idea is that it isn't readily possible to determine what the minimum actually is, or whether you succeeded in setting it as the backlog queue length.

> It appears that new incoming connections shouldn't affect established connections, though I've been unable to find any definitive answer in any text.

That is correct. There is no reason why it *should* affect them: that's why you won't find it written down anywhere, any more than the fact that the phase of the moon doesn't affect it either.

> Is it possible for failed new incoming connections to create some kind of TCP traffic congestion on the server with the packets it's receiving

No.

> or are they dropped fast enough that it has no effect on any buffers or other part of the network stack?

They're not dropped. They simply aren't even created if they won't fit on the backlog queue. Ergo their resource consumption at the server is zero.

> Specifically the platform in use is Linux, and although it may be handled differently in different OSs, I expect them to all behave roughly the same.

They don't. On Windows, an incoming connection when the backlog queue is full causes an RST to be issued. On other platforms it is simply ignored.

Comment: Thanks for that. 

> "They're not dropped. They simply aren't even created if they won't fit on the backlog queue. Ergo their resource consumption at the server is zero."

I find this interesting since there are some web resources that suggest setting the backlog high helps slightly against DDoS attacks, yet it would seem to me that servicing requests as fast as you get them and preventing any tcp packets being generated at all if there's a huge backlog would be more beneficial.

Comment: I don't know why setting a high backlog would help but I haven't seen the resources you mention. Can you provide a citation? It seems to me that the backlog queue should be used for the purpose it was intended for: to allow clients to connect while you're busy. Preventing attacks is the province of the firewall. And you should *always* service requests as fast as you can, regardless of attacks.

Comment: Thanks again. I realise that one link does not constitute gospel, though the link in question was https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/configtuning-kernel-limits.html where it discusses adjusting the somaxconn value. I am indeed already servicing requests as fast as they possibly can be.

Comment: Well it's a decent source. Shame there isn't more detail. I suppose a longer backlog queue effectively expands the service itself, so denying it becomes harder.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe are several types of attacks like flooding, syn attacks and other goodies resulting in denial of service.

This topic is not easy, because protection has to be implemented in all the layers, including TCP. For instance a SYN attack, fiddling with the sequence numbers, ... . At that point the packet in question already came a long way, through the ethernet layer and ip layer, bottom line it is taking resources. So if your system is under attack, the attacking packets are in your data stream just like the good ones are. The faster you can detect a packet is faulty and drop it, the better. Usually a system that is under attack will be slower. Well at least the systems that I have worked with.

Some attacks try to bring your system in a faulty state permanently, this by exploiting bugs. For instance TCP has a receive queue, if packets are constantly arriving out of order they will be stored in that receive queue. If the missing packet never arrives, then this receive queue could keep on growing and growing. Without the proper defense , this would lead to the system going completely out of resources.

There are specialised tools (codenumicon for instance) to check the vulnerability of a TCP stack implementation. You can assume that the one on linux has been properly tested using similar tools.

An attack can also occur on the application layer. If you have a TCP server and it allows only a limited amount of sessions. A malicious user can simply take all the connections simply by establishing all the connections and then not doing anything with it. So you have to create some defense as well. Weather or not you set this limit very low or high does not change a thing. A malicious user will try anything to bring your system down. You need to built in defense anyway. You can connect to a webserver (HTTP) simply using telnet. If you don't send anything the server's defense will come into play and close the connection.

So bringing the amount of possible connections to a low value and thinking that this in itself is a form of protection is indeed naive.

> Is it possible for failed new incoming connections to create some kind of TCP traffic congestion on the server with the packets it's receiving or are they dropped fast enough that it has no effect on any buffers or other part of the network stack?

They are using resources of your machine and will make your system run slower.

> It appears that new incoming connections shouldn't affect established connections, though I've been unable to find any definitive answer in any text.

If it is normal user trying to establish a connection, even if he is doing it continuously, retrying upon failure. The influence will be minimal, close to nothing. But a malicious user that is flooding connections attempts will have influence on the system performance, because the system has to spent time identifying those flawed packets and dropping them asap.

Comment: TCP has a *bounded* receive queue, the socket receive buffer, which, being bounded, does not 'lead to the system going completely out of resources'. And out-of-order packets are often just dropped rather than stored.

Comment: Out of order packets are only dropped if they are out of the current TCP receive window. If there would be no storing of these segments, then the sender would have to retransmit, relying on the retransmission timer, ... causing slower transmission speeds. And it is not the socket receive queue that is able to do that, it is the TCP receive queue. The socket layer and TCP layer are 2 distinct layers.